# How to implement IIdentity for a custom User object in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

In my ASP.NET MVC app, I'm trying to create a custom HttpContent.User object. I've started by creating a Member class, which implements IPrincioal.

```
public class Member : IPrincipal
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IIdentity Identity { get; set; }
    public bool IsInRole(string role) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    ...
}
```

Then at authentication time I set HttpContext.User to an instance of a Member class:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
HttpContext.User = member;
```

Then later I want to check if the user is authenticated, like so:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { ... }
```

That's where I'm stuck. **I'm not sure what I need to do for the `public IIdentity Identity` property on the instance of the Member.** So that I can use the HttpContext.User object something like this:

```
IsAuthenticated = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
ViewBag.IsAuthenticated = IsAuthenticated;

if (IsAuthenticated) {
    CurrentMember = (Member)HttpContext.User;
    ViewBag.CurrentMember = CurrentMember;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you will find this useful https://github.com/moov2/dotnet-mvc-boilerplate if you were to study the *SessionAuthentication* class, the *LoginController* and *Global.asax.cs*

Comment: Annd what is exactly your trouble with implementing simple IIdentity (or even using GenericIdentity)?

Comment: I've never done it before... searching Google for `custom user.identity` wasn't proving helpful. Do you know of some good examples I can look at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Principal is not something you can just set once when writing the auth cookie and forget later. During subsequent requests, the auth cookie is read and the `IPrincipal` / `IIdentity` is reconstructed before executing an action method. When that happens, trying to cast the `HttpContext.User` to your custom `Member` type will throw an exception.

One option would be to intercept in an `ActionFilter`, and just wrap the standard implementation.

```
public class UsesCustomPrincipalAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var systemPrincipal = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        var customPrincipal = new Member(systemPrincipal)
        {
            Id = "not sure where this comes from",
        };
        filterContext.HttpContext.User = customPrincipal;
    }
}

public class Member : IPrincipal
{
    private readonly IPrincipal _systemPrincipal;

    public Member(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("principal");
        _systemPrincipal = principal;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IIdentity Identity { get { return _systemPrincipal.Identity; } }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return _systemPrincipal.IsInRole(role);
    }
}
```

This way, you're not losing anything that comes out of the box with the default `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` implementations. You can still invoke `IsAuthenticated` on the `IIdentity`, or even `IsInRole(string)` on the `IPrincipal`. The only thing you're gaining is the extra `Id` property on your custom `IPrincipal` implementation (though I'm not sure where this comes from or why you need it).

Comment: Thank you, the Member class I posted was trimmed for brevity, there are many more properties. I'm not at my workstation right now, I'll look things over later. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, well, it seems perhaps I shouldn't be doing this then. I was hoping that tying into `FormsAuthentication`, and `HttpContext.User`, that I could bypass doing it manually. I currently use a few `Session` variables, setting them on `OnActionExecuting`. Thanks for the info.